# Android NDK: Strange lines coordinates in OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm rendering simple scene with library GLESv1_CM on Android with NDK.

```
void render(Rect viewport)
{
  glViewport(viewport.left, viewport.top, viewport.Width(), viewport.Height());
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);   
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrthof(viewport.left, viewport.right, viewport.top, viewport.bottom, -1, 1);
  GLfloat points[] = { 5, 50, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                       7, 50, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                       7, 50, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                       7, 52, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                       8, 50, 0, 1, 0, 1,
                      10, 50, 0, 1, 0, 1};
  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
  glVertexPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,sizeof(GLfloat)*6,&points);
  glColorPointer(4,GL_FLOAT,sizeof(GLfloat)*6,&points[2]);
  glDrawArrays(GL_LINES,0,6);
  glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}
```

I wish to have 3 crossed lines, but when I run it on device with android 2.2 or 3.2 i have this:

[image: screen from Android 2.2 device]

Even more, on Android emulator with Android 4 (update: same on emulator with 2.3) i have this:

[image: screen from Android 4 emulator]

Is it possible to make it looks like on this picture on all devices with all Android versions without using opengl2?

[image: wanted screen]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm) for this type of projection:

> If exact pixelization is required, you might want to put a small
>   translation in the ModelView matrix, as shown below:
>
> ```
> glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
> glLoadIdentity ();
> glTranslatef (0.375, 0.375, 0.);
> ```

I imagine this reduces the likelihood of rounding issues.

Comment: unfortunately this solution doesn't work. It only moves all points to top-right, as it should do. I think it because it was written for 2d over 3d, and at second, it was written for opengl2 and not for opengl es. But thank you for interesting link

Comment: Er, no.  If you have a orthographic projection in which world coordinates map precisely to screen pixels, then that code snippet adjusts by 0.375 of a pixel. It certainly won't move "all points to top-right". Perhaps you have a different modelview matrix... your original question doesn't include it, so I assumed it was the identity matrix.

Comment: ok, i correct a little bit my code and now it works. Not as perfect as I wish, but much better. thank you

Comment: You could try other adjustment values. I don't know why the FAQ recommends 0.375 in particular, I'd have thought 0.5 would be a more logical choice.